# PATH in terminal and in PHP is different

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have next result of command **sudo -u www-data echo $PATH** in terminal:

```
/home/denis/node-v0.12.0/bin:/home/denis/node-v0.12.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

I have next result in PHP if I run command **echo `echo \$PATH`**:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

PATH in terminal and in PHP is different. I don't understand why.

Comment: Check which user actually runs that php script.

Comment: Which user runs what script is irrelevant. Daemons do not start from a login shell. Sudo inherits your current environment unless configured to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the command literally as given

```
sudo -u www-data echo $PATH
```

the `$PATH` is expanded by your shell before doing a `sudo` (and show *your* `$PATH`).  However, if you quoted this properly, it could be deferred into the sudo'd user, and expose a different problem.

Unless you make special provision for this (an option to `sudo`, which may/may not work), environment variables such as `PATH` are reset to system defaults when using `sudo`.  For further discussion see

- [How to keep Environment Variables when Using SUDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo)
- [How do I make sudo preserve my environment variables?](https://superuser.com/questions/232231/how-do-i-make-sudo-preserve-my-environment-variables)

Comment: I have changed PATH in PHP according this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696230/how-to-set-global-environment-variables-for-php