# Setting array as environment variable for exec() in apache2

Tags: bash, apache

I use apache2 server and i need to execute bash scripts on server. So i use `exec()` function. For my scripts i should define environment variables but apache sends me an error when i'm trying to start server with my bash-like definition:

```
/etc/apache2/envvars: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Syntax `export MY_ARRAY = (1 2 3)` works in terminal but doesn't works by placing in apache's `envvars` file.

So how can i define array environment variable to work with in other scripts by using php function `exec()`?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplication question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696230/how-to-set-global-environment-variables-for-php

Comment: Not at all, because when i set regular values like:
"export VALUE = 1.5" 
in /etc/apache2/envvars it does work. I have problems only with arrays and it's another problem, i guess.