# How do I set the path in Apache for ImageMagick so I can run from PHP system()?

Tags: php, apache, centos, imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick for image conversion, called from PHP using `system('convert -option $file ...')`

This works fine for me on one instance (CentOS 6), but fails silently on another instance (CentOS 5 where ImageMagick is in /usr/local/bin).  On that one, I have to run `system('/usr/local/bin/convert -option $file ...')`

Question is, how do I set the path in Apache so `convert` works without the preceding `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 0):

You can export /usr/local/bin to ImageMagick into your PATH environment variable. This is often done via your .profile or .bash_profile.

For example you can see what is in your PATH via

```
echo $PATH
```

If it does not include /usr/local/bin, then edit your .profile file (simple text) and add

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: That's the thing, I can run convert from the command line no problem.  But PHP system() can't  (php with apache)

Comment: Sorry I am not a PHP expert. But check your PHP environment variables or your phpinfo.php. Do a Google search or check out http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696230/how-to-set-global-environment-variables-for-php