# Undefined index - Apache - Environment Variables

Tags: php, apache

I have cloned PHP code from a Linux server onto a Windows WAMP server. When I run the index.php page the error in the picture appears. From what I can work out in my Windows WAMP server the environment variables have not been initialized.

How do I initialize these variables in the environment?

Thank you.

```
DB::init([
    'host'              => $_ENV['DB_HOST'],
    'database'          => $_ENV['DB_DATABASE'],
    'user'              => $_ENV['DB_USERNAME'],
    'password'          => $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'],
]);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCxwT.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set global environment variables for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696230/how-to-set-global-environment-variables-for-php)

Comment: I have a file in the directory:C:\WAMP\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\conf called httpd. 

I have entered into it:

SetEnv DB_DATABASE 'pettbot'

I entered this text in a random place and it is not inside any tags as I'm not sure what the tags would be. It still does not work. Have I neglected to put appropriate tags around it? Am I using the right file? Is my syntax correct?

Comment: It doesn't need to be within any tags. Did you restart Apache?

Comment: I have restarted Apache and the problems remains.

Comment: Does the value come through if you use `getenv('DB_DATABASE')` in the PHP?

Comment: Yes. Why is there a difference between $_ENV[ ] and getenv()?

Answer (score -1):

The DB initialization method is looking for the host, database, user and password to be defined somewhere.

I'd recommend setting them in a config file that is ignored by any SVN (git, etc). You'd end up with a file that looks like this:

```
$_ENV['DB_HOST'] = //name_of_your_host;
$_ENV['DB_DATABASE'] = //name_of_database_to_start_in;
$_ENV['DB_USER'] = //name_of_mysql_user_to_access_database_above;
$_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] = //password_of_user_above;
```

Fill in the commented parts, and include this before you call your DB::init.
One very, very, very important part to remember is **do not include the config file in your git or other repository!!** Otherwise, if your repository is compromised, the attacker will have access to both a valid DB_USER and DB_PASSWORD!!