# How to change USER , HOME path in RHEL 8

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables, rhel, rhel8

I tried to change HOME, USER in phpinfo() under environment module by setting envars, apachectl in /etc/httpd/ path but it's not working. Any clue to solve it?

**ENVVARS FILE**

```
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/oracle/19.11/client64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 export TNS_ADMIN=/etc
 export HOME=/var/www/html
```

**APACHECTL FILE**

```
 HTTPD='/etc/httpd -f 
 /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf'
 if test -f /etc/httpd/envvars; then
 . /etc/httpd/envvars
fi
```

[image]

Comment: `$HOME` is set from by shell from `/etc/passwd` file. Question is, why you want to change it? It may not be good idea.

Comment: @TomášJacík in my production site it's different and custom path is there. So, that's why I want to change it. Also, I want to set ORACLE_HOME environment variable but unable to do so. Could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: I'm not RHEL guy, so I don't know why setting in `/etc/httpd/envvars` doesn't work (it should). Try grep for proper path in `/etc` on you production site, maybe you will see where else is `HOME` set.