# Ubuntu: How PHP can read Environment Variable

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, environment-variables

I'm running on Ubuntu server 14.04.

I have a PHP file that needs to read an environment variable and use it.

How can I do that?

Comment: Is this script to be run in a web server, or on the console?

Answer (score 9):

If you run a PHP file (e.g. test.php) on Ubuntu server and you need to read and use an environment variable, you need to do the following:

1. Edit the *.bashrc* file (in case you run *bash* as a shell)

   ```
   # Add the following:
   export DB_NAME="My database name"
   ```

   **IMPORTANT:** Do not forget the **export** word!
2. Save the file and exit.
3. click the following command:

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```
4. check that the Environment variable is valid

   ```
   echo $DB_NAME
   ```

   It should print:

   ```
   My database name
   ```
5. Edit your PHP file:

   ```
   <?php
     $db = getenv('DB_NAME'); // Gets the database name
     echo "Database name: $db  \r\n"
   ?>
   ```
6. Run the PHP file

   ```
   php test.php
   ```

   It should print

   ```
   Database name: My Database name
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of doing it and its doing this on the apache side incase you want to migrate the change on to another server:

Basically it's having the following entry in 
/etc/environment file

```
export MY_PROJECT_PATH=/var/www/my-project
export MY_PROJECT_ENV=production
export MY_PROJECT_MAIL=support@my-project.com

export MY_TETS_ENV=my_test_env_value
```

You'll need to configure apache to read those environment variables.

This has already been answered on stack overflow: 
@ref: [How to get system environment variables into PHP while running CLI & Apache2Handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568191/how-to-get-system-environment-variables-into-php-while-running-cli-apache2hand)