# Expose environment variables to Apache and PHP

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, docker

## Background

I'm trying to use [Wercker](http://wercker.com/) to run my test for a PHP application. Wercker uses Docker containers to setup a test environment to execute tests in. It uses Environment Variables to expose the connection params for any connected services like MySQL and Elasticsearch. Example MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR = 127.0.1.1

My core Docker containers is running Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP and Apache already installed on the container.

## Problem

I can't seem to access the Environment Variables via php $_SERVER or $_ENV when running via Apache. It works fine if I run the script via CLI `php ./db_connect.php` or if I run PHP using its build in server `php -S localhost:8000`. However If I try and access a page via the Apache virtual host, the Environment Variables are not available.

## Progress

I have setup Apache with the mod used to allow environmental variables "I think"

```
sudo a2enmod env
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I'm trying to access the Environment Variables in my script.

```
$database_host      = $_SERVER["MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR"];
$database_username  = $_SERVER["MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_USER"];
$database_password  = $_SERVER["MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_PASSWORD"];
$database_name      = $_SERVER["MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_DATABASE"];
$elasticsearch_host = $_SERVER["ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_9300_TCP_ADDR"];
```

I can add new variables in my .htaccess, I just don't get all the system environmental variables.

```
SetEnv TEST_VAR test
```

I have read this question [How to get system environment variables into PHP while running CLI & Apache2Handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568191/how-to-get-system-environment-variables-into-php-while-running-cli-apache2hand) but i'm not sure what its suggesting to do.

## Question

How do I expose System Environment Variables to Apache and PHP?

Comment: Have you tried `$_ENV['MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR']` ? Note that the environment variables for links are deprecated, and no longer set for the new custom networks in docker 1.9 and above. A better way is to connect using the name of the container that's linked, e.g. `http://mysql` to connect to the "mysql" container. The environment variables didn't add much, because you need both the *name* and the *port* number to obtain the ip-address, so using the name of the container is easier anyway.

Comment: Yes, have tried to access the environment variables from $_ENV and $HTTP_ENV_VARS just to be sure. The container link solution may work, the only problem is that the container exposes additional information like the database table it creates on setup  $_SERVER["MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_DATABASE"] and the random root password $_SERVER['MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'] that I also need.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using [php official Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) you have to explicitly pass environment variables from Apache to PHP.
You can do something like this:

In your Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
RUN echo 'SetEnv MYSQL_USER ${MYSQL_USER}' > /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/environment.conf
```

`environment.conf` is an arbitrary name, but it should be placed in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/`.

In docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    yourservice:
        build: ./yourimage
        image: yourimage
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        volumes:
            - ../html:/var/www/html
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: foo
```

In your PHP script:

```
echo getenv('MYSQL_USER');
```

Comment: Best answer. No need to mess with config files any more than necessary. Very simple solution, while keeping all control in the Dockerfile/docker-compose.

Comment: Works like a charm. This is definitely the way to go!

Comment: Nice solution! One recommendation would be to use `>>` instead of `>` in order not to loose previous contents of the `environment.conf` file, if any.

Comment: Interestingly, when I set the `SetEnv variable value` in a file within the `conf.d/` folder so as to make it available to all of the server, `getenv('variable')` returns false. But, `$_SERVER['variable']` returns `value`.  If I set it in the Apache VirtualHost section, `getenv('variable)` returns `value`. I am on a Cent OS 7 with PHP 7.2 and Apache 2.4. Not sure if others ran into something similar.

Comment: Note this works because `'${MYSQL_USER}'` is evaluated at runtime, not build time. For build time passing of variables, compose yaml file uses `build: ... args: XY`

Answer (score 7):

**Here is the solution:**

Docker will pass these to apache but you have to configure apache to make them available to PHP.

Setup the values in your local .env file

```
MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR=1234
MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_USER=development
MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
```

Then add these as environment params in the docker-compose.yml file

```
version: 2
services:
  web:
  build: php:5.6-apache
  environment:
    MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR:${MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR}
    MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_USER}
    MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
```

Then to pass these to PHP set these as environment params in your Virtual Host config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName some-project

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/some-project

    # Set apache environment variables
    SetEnv MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR ${MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR}
    SetEnv MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_USER ${MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_USER}
    SetEnv MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_PASSWORD ${MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
</VirtualHost>
```

These will now be available to access in PHP via the $_SERVER super global array.

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER['MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_USER'];
```

Answer (score 2):

if you're using **php-fpm**, you can pass env vars from OS to PHP-FPM through `clear_env` ini setting in a file like `/path/to/php/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`:

```
clear_env = no
```

it works with `environment` vars set via **docker-compose.yml** as below:

```yaml
version: "..."

services:
    php-fpm:
        image: php:7-fpm
        environment:
            MY_VAR: my-value
```

**IMPORTANT:** Of course, the risk is that your PHP-FPM will get access to all OS env vars. If passing all vars is a problem, you can also pass only specific vars via `www.conf` or another php ini config file:

```
; Pass environment variables like LD_LIBRARY_PATH. All $VARIABLEs are taken from
; the current environment.
env[MY_VAR] = $MY_VAR
```

Answer (score 1):

With docker-compose you can retrieve the operating system's environment variables set with the `environment` option of the docker-compose.yml file through php's `$_ENV` variable.

```
version: 2
services:
  web:
    build: php:5.6-apache
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: "user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "passwd"
```

should give you

```
$_ENV['MYSQL_USER'] = user
$_ENV['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = passwd
```

I'm not sure how Wercker maps environment variables to the containers, but there's this open issue that I think might help
https://github.com/wercker/wercker/issues/63

Comment: Indeed that is what *should* work, but based on what I've experienced, and the question, it seems that "docker + apache + php" doesn't necessarily pass those environment variables through to php. IDK under what circumstances this is a problem, but I have seen this in an environment that didn't include wercker - so it is something about apache settings, or how docker passes the variables to apache.

Comment: Setting `environment` only in docker-compose.yml is not sufficient to pass variables to PHP. The variables listed in `environment` will be available in Apache config files, in the form ${MYSQL_USER}, but you'll also have to use SetEnv directive in Apache config to pass the variables down to PHP. See my answer for a complete example.

Answer (score -3):

you can check get env with php command like below

```
php -r "echo getenv('MYSQL_USER');"
```

Comment: Note that this invokes the PHP CLI, not the Apache process. The poster is not having problems accessing variables when invoking the CLI.