# Laravel 5.2 get Linux system environment variables

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a possibility to get some Linux system environment variables and still use the .env variables?

We want to use an auto-generated database password that's set as Linux environment variable but can't get Laravel to find the Linux system environment variables.

Comment: as per my knowledge, you cannot use Linux environment variable directly, you have to run shell commands, grab your variable and assign it to Laravel global variable for internal use

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568191/how-to-get-system-environment-variables-into-php-while-running-cli-apache2hand have you looked at it?

Comment: Any reason this question is still open?

Answer (score 2):

Use the getenv() function of PHP.

[PHP: getenv - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php)

Answer (score 1):

Linux system variables cannot be access through PHP/Apache. You could set a variable in the Apache Vhost of your site via [SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) and grab it in Laravel.

You could do

- Apache: `SetEnv DB_Pass dbpassword123` in your Vhost
- Nginx: `fastcgi_param DB_Pass dbpassword123`

**Example Apache Vhost:**

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
    ServerAdmin root@mpj.local.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName mpj.local.dev

    SetEnv DB_Pass dbpassword123

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

and fetch the variable `DB_Pass` in Laravel with

```
$dbPass = env('DB_Pass');
```

Comment: Halfway there. It is very possible, the variables just have to be passed into the HTTP server first. As @NabinKunwar shared, see [How to get system environment variables into PHP while running CLI & Apache2Handler?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23635043/5816643).

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'env' function.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: The env function is limited to Laravel project environment variables, we're not able to get the Linux system environment variables.

Comment: Well, you need to export you variable to be accessible by any user.
/etc/profile.d must be a good start point.