# How can I use getenv in PHP?

Tags: php, getenv

I have written the following code: test.php

```
 $java_path=getenv("JAVA_HOME");
 echo 'Java Path : '.$java_path ."<br>";
```

when I run through command prompt (Ubuntu terminal) like:

```
>php test.php

Output: 
Java Path : /opt/jdk1.8.0_161
```

I get the expected output, but when I run it through browser (Firefox),

http://localhost/test.php

I get empty value for Java Path.
Output:
Java Path :

Comment: What do you mean by `I run through browser(Firefox), I get empty value for Java Path.`? As in you were hopeful that a PHP function would return what the java home path is on a browser?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Is that path also set on the server you are running?

Comment: its maybe because `JAVA_HOME` is being set for your user not for `www-data` that your webserver does its query with,

Comment: This is because CLI is running as your user with _you_ env variables; the "browser" is using a server (apache, fastcgi, etc). This question here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568191/how-to-get-system-environment-variables-into-php-while-running-cli-apache2hand

Comment: hppycoder                                                        
 on command prompt (terminal) file get executed and I get output. But when I run through browser like
localhost/test.php.                                                 
 I get nothing output.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it